# Shape Transformation Via Medial Axis Transform

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons, voronoi-diagram

Let $P_1,\dots,P_n$ be simple polygons which don't intersect each other and $S\subseteq\mathbf{R}^2$ the set of points lying in the interior of an odd number of the $P_i$, so $S$ can be thought as the interior of a finite number of simple polygons, each with a finite number of holes, also described by simple polygons.  I want to perform the following transformation to $S$:

- Apply medial axis transform, i.e. get the set $\textsf{MAT}(S)$ of triples $(x,y,r)$ such that the open ball $B_r(x,y)$ is contained in $S$ but not strictly contained in another open ball $B_{r'}(x',y')\subseteq S$.
- Given a bijective linear map $f:\mathbf{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^2$, construct the shape $$S_f:=f^{-1}(\cup_{(x,y,r)\in\textsf{MAT}(S)}B_r(f(x,y)).$$  In other words, for each $(x,y,r)\in\textsf{MAT}(S)$, draw the squeezed ball $f^{-1}(B_1(0,0))$ centered at $(x,y)$ and scaled by $r$ on the plane.

The lines in the medial axis transform don't have to be straight, but I have the hunch that $S_f$ can again be described via polygons like $S$.  If that's correct, is there an easy way to directly compute the line segments of $S_f$, without computing the medial axis transform first?  What if we look at balls in another $p$-norm?

[EDIT] No, $S_f$ can't be described via polygons in general.  But maybe for certain $f$?

Comment: What exactly is a simple polygon with holes?

Comment: Is there a better term?  I mean a finite set of non-intersecting polygons, and by interior I mean the set of points lying the interior of exactly one of the polygons.

Comment: Made an edit, better now?